# Recalculating dominance after changing the entry node

Tags: graphs

I'm working with a control-flow graph, which is simply a directed (usually cyclic) graph with an entry (initial) node, and I have calculated all the [dominators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)) on the graph. It's noteworth that every node has either 1 or 2 transitions.

I need now to change the entry node of the graph to *a node to which the entry node has a transition to*. Since I do use dominator information for the internal representation of the graphs (similar to nested scopes in programming languages), I'm basically rewriting the graph after a single transition from the entry node.

For example, I have Graph 1 and I want to rewrite it to Graph 2:

[image]
[image]

Here I'm changing the entry node from a to b (and this is the only possible transformation, since a only had a transition to b). On Graph 2 I could possibly do the same (but then I'd have two options, moving the entry node to c or d).

Since I need the dominance information, I'd have to recalculate it after every change. My question is: is there any property for directed graphs that would allow me to do this in an optimal way, instead of recalculating all dominators from scratch?

(Also, since I do use dominance information for the internal representation... could there be a purely syntactical transformation to find dominance information?)